# Manipulate column data to new format by using Python in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to manipulate my data. I have data that looks like this:

```
CarModel ProductionData ProductionYear
BMWX1    55000          2005
Accord   100000         2005
BMWX1    34000          2006
Accord   110000         2006
BMWX1    43000          2007
Accord   105000         2007
```

How can I make the data look like this?

```
CarModel NewColumn
BMWX1    [2005.0, 2006.0, 55000]; [2006.0, 2007.0, 34000]; [2007.0, 2008.0,      43000]
Accord   [2005.0, 2006.0, 100000]; [2006.0, 2007.0, 110000]; [2007.0, 2008.0,      105000]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please can you show your efforts as SO is not a code writing service, also can you explain what the desired result represents as I don't understand where the 2008 value comes from and your grouping

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below produces the output you describe. Group on the `CarModel` (either as `column` or moved to the `index`) and then return the respective columns as `.values`.

```
df['Year2'] = df.ProductionYear.add(1)
df.groupby('CarModel').apply(lambda x: x.loc[:, ['ProductionYear', 'Year2', 'ProductionData']].values)

CarModel
Accord    [[2005, 2006, 100000], [2006, 2007, 110000], [...
BMWX1     [[2005, 2006, 55000], [2006, 2007, 34000], [20...
dtype: object
```

Comment: Right now get the result and new column:                                                                       CarModel Year   Year2 Production Data
BMWX1 2000 2001 10
Accord 2000 2001 7
BMWX1 2001 2002 5
Accord 2001 2002 8                                                                       I am try to use .format to change the new column to look like this:        CarModel    New Data Format
BMWX1    <[2000.0, 2001.0, 10]; [2001.0, 2002.0, 5]>
Accord    <[2000.0, 2001.0, 7]; [2001.0, 2002.0, 8]>                                 Do you have any further suggestions?  Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand. You do realize that the other answer is just a copy of mine, right?

Comment: I tried both of those solutions in the morning and get similar results. The comment I left is a kind of following up question. I am sorry for any confusing. This is the first time I use stackoverflow. I put those data as a table format in the comment. But it shows up like a sentence... So sorry for that.

Comment: You should just pay attention to who posts first. But never mind.

Answer (score 0):

## Setup

```
text = """CarModel ProductionData ProductionYear
BMWX1    55000          2005
Accord   100000         2005
BMWX1    34000          2006
Accord   110000         2006
BMWX1    43000          2007
Accord   105000         2007"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1)
```

## Solution

```
gb = df.set_index('CarModel').groupby(level=0)

def proc_df(df):
    # Add this column becuase OP has it in final output
    df['Year2'] = df.ProductionYear + 1

    columns = ['ProductionYear', 'Year2', 'ProductionData']

    # Return ndarray gets flattened to string when returned via apply
    return df[columns].values

gb.apply(proc_df)
```

Looks like:

```
CarModel
Accord    [[2005, 2006, 100000], [2006, 2007, 110000], [...
BMWX1     [[2005, 2006, 55000], [2006, 2007, 34000], [20...
dtype: object
```

Comment: Right now get the result and new column:                                                                       CarModel Year   Year2 Production Data
BMWX1 2000 2001 10
Accord 2000 2001 7
BMWX1 2001 2002 5
Accord 2001 2002 8                                                                       I am try to use .format to change the new column to look like this:        CarModel    New Data Format
BMWX1    <[2000.0, 2001.0, 10]; [2001.0, 2002.0, 5]>
Accord    <[2000.0, 2001.0, 7]; [2001.0, 2002.0, 8]>                                 Do you have any further suggestions?  Thank you very much.

Comment: This looks familiar. Why was setting `CarModel` as index the trick?

Comment: It was appending it to index that was the trick.  That enabled the dataframe to have a unique index, capitalizing on the existing default index.  Then I had an existing order to the sub-dataframe within the groupby's apply.  I thought I needed it for some step.  Turns out I don't.  Thanks for calling me out on that.

Comment: You could have seen from my answer already that it was working fine without. Also, what is the benefit of wrapping the same function that I use as `lambda` into a named function, other than to extend the number of lines necessary?

Comment: There was no intended point to using the same function.  My answer was independent of yours regardless of the similarities.  Often times, multiple people whom are all familiar with a subject will devise similar solutions.  I know that my answers are not always optimal.  But its what I came up with.